# Marking full weeks inside a month including remaining days from other months

Tags: date, sas, week-number

I have a dataset with daily data. I need to create a variable which brings the number of the week in each month (1 to (4 or 5)).

I have reached that with the following formula:

```
 WK_NUM = intck('week',intnx('month',DATE,0),DATE)+1;
```

It works fine, but frequently the first and the last weeks of the month aren't full weeks, so the line only brings partial weeks. I need to improve it to bring remaining days from previous or next month in order to fill each week with 7 days.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show what you're starting with and what you need as output?

Comment: My database covers JAN15 until today. Let's use MAY2017 as example. I have multiple lines of data for each date, and the field DATE contains the complete date of it (MAY01 to MAY31). I want to create a variable called WK_NUM which group these days by week (1st to 5th). My currently formula does it, but my first week covers MAY01 to MAY06 (6 days), and my last week MAY28 to MAY31 (4 days). In these cases, I want it to get more days from previous/next months in ordem to fill a complete 7 day's week (from sunday to saturday), like APR30 to MAY06 (1st week) and MAY28 to JUN03 (last week).

Comment: Please add that text to the question. Or better yet, add to the question to show a few example records  of the data you have, and the show the output data you would want from that example.

Comment: @AYJK As noted, please add this to the question. Also include how you handle that when you're looking at the next month? So June 1 would be Week5? Have you tried the variants of the WEEK function/format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this creates the expected result:

```
/* initial data set with dates */
data a;
  format date date9.;
  do date="15apr2017"d to "15jun2017"d;
   output;
  end;
 run;

/* adding week number */
data a;
  set a;
  wk_num = week(date,'u');
run;

/* selecting May and modifying wk_num */
proc sql noprint;
  CREATE TABLE b AS
  SELECT date
    ,wk_num - ((SELECT min(wk_num) FROM a WHERE date="01may2017"d)-1)
  FROM a
  WHERE wk_num between (SELECT min(wk_num) FROM a WHERE date="01may2017"d) AND (SELECT max(wk_num) FROM a WHERE date="31may2017"d)
  ;
quit;
```

Option for week function:

**u** (default): specifies the number-of-the-week within the year. Sunday is considered the first day of the week. The number-of-the-week value is represented as a decimal number in the range 0-53. Week 53 has no special meaning. The value of week('31dec2006'd, 'u') is 53.

**v**: specifies the number-of-the-week whose value is represented as a decimal number in the range 1-53. Monday is considered the first day of the week and week 1 of the year is the week that includes both January 4th and the first Thursday of the year. If the first Monday of January is the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th, the preceding days are part of the last week of the preceding year.

**w**: specifies the number-of-the-week within the year. Monday is considered the first day of the week. The number-of-the-week value is represented as a decimal number in the range 0-53. Week 53 has no special meaning. The value of week('31dec2006'd, 'w') is 53.

Comment: Thank you @zuluk, it worked just like I wanted! Cheers.